kafka ports 29092 and 9092
Lets say I have kafka
 broker:
image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.5.0
hostname: broker
container_name: broker
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
ports:
  - "9092:9092"
  - "29092:29092"
  - "9101:9101"
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
  KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
  KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

with ports 9092 29092. I'm using 29092 in my Spring Boot application. How is it differrent from port 9092. What the difference between ports 29092 9092 in kafka?

Does Connect to Kafka running in Docker answer your question?  (There is a lot there, both in the question and in the answers.)  When a client connects to Kafka, the broker responds with a listing of all of the available brokers, and the names that are usable are different if you're connecting from another container vs. from the host outside a container.

The difference is what you've specified them to be in KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS. Each is used in a different network context.
Post-connection, each individual broker returns its own advertised listeners to the clients.
If you try to connect from outside of Docker to localhost:29092, you'll get some error about unknown host: broker (for this reason you should remove 29092:29092 from the ports list), similarly if you use broker:9092 from a container, it'll fail to connect to localhost since that's not where kafka is running.
This blog goes into the details of the network relationship https://confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/
